# PHP/SQL Check if a similar entry already exists in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search on my website and im trying to show a list of the most popular search terms on my site it sort of works but it isn't matching the strings close enough.

This is what i'm currently using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE r_name LIKE '%".$searchname."%' OR r_number like '%".$searchname."%'
```

However if a user searches for say `Game Name` and another searches for `Game Name (Reviews)` it will add 2 entries into my database, Is there a way to do a similarity test before entering the entry ?

Comment: Ah the great question of search algorithms. It's hard to pinpoint an exact answer. The solution involves breaking down $searchname by its search terms and evaluating each search term by itself to build a "relevance" value that can be used to determine if the entire phrase can be thrown away or stored as its own search within your "search terms" table.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a way but it requires you to fiddle with it a little. there is a search called 
SOUNDEX, which will match things that are very close. It might not be a perfect solution to your question, but it is definitely something that might get you started in the right direction.

`SELECT * FROM db WHERE SOUNDEX( db.r_name ) LIKE SOUNDEX( '{$searchname}' );`

I believe that if you have an entry 'lowercasexd' , and do soundex like('what is lowercasexd?'), it will find the entry that's associated with 'lowercasexd'. 
Be aware that this type of search take a little while to run compare to '=' searches on indexed databases(on my database it does about 5-6k entries per second) so it is NOT recommended for anything big. If you want a near-perfect solution, I suggest you read about google's search mechanism, and look up some search engine source code if your project is significant enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have around 18193 entries in the database so not a huge amount. I will give your solution a try. Will it use alot of server resources as im only on a VPS.

Comment: If you index your tabase back and forth, AND enable query caching, thread caching, and optimize everything to its fullest all queries will only take ~5 seconds on 2.4M entry database. Everything depends on how optimized your database is. If you are looking at optimization tools I suggest `mysqltuner.pl`. it is a small script that will help you greatly. You can configure how much RAM your machine will use, and the more RAM/Harddrive space you use for optimization, the less CPU you will have to use.